# Change output path for Web API project and avoid "Could not load type..." exception when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

My solution consists of several projects. Some of them are desktop-specific, some of them are "shared", some of them (new ones) will be a web part of solution.

For now, desktop and shared projects have similar output path settings:

- ..\bin\debug for debug configuration;
- ..\bin\release for release configuration.

Since I'm learning MVC and Web API, I've played around with a number of sample projects, and I know, that changing default output path will raise "Could not load type..." exception when debugging.

Usually, solutions are to restore default output path, but I want to keep solution structure, thus, I want to set output path to values listed above.

Is there any reasonable way to achieve this?